# http redirect loop using location in web.config

Tags: html, asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication

I have a website inside which I have a directory I want to keep private. My login page is inside this directory called admin.aspx.

In my main Web.Config I have the following block:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/admin.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
</authentication>
```

And then in my subdirectory I have a second web.config file with the following:

```
  <location path="admin.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

However when I try to get to admin.aspx I get this error:

```
The web page at http://localhost:51167/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252Fadmin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252fAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252fadmin has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
```

I don't understand why it's got itself in a loop. If I change web.config (inside the directory) to simply say:

```
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

I can get to it so is it something with the location option?

Thanks.